# How is cursor_pos() in termion bound to stdout?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm relatively new to Rust, so this might be a really obvious question, but here goes. I'm trying to determine (from the code) what object a particular trait is bound to. If I look at the [termion](https://github.com/redox-os/termion/) library, there is a trait called `DetermineCursorPos` with a single method [cursor_pos()](https://docs.rs/termion/latest/termion/cursor/trait.DetectCursorPos.html). In one of the examples, it is shown to be bound to [`stdout`](https://github.com/redox-os/termion/blob/master/examples/mouse.rs#L29). My question is this: if this example didn't exist, how would I know to use `cursor_pos()` on `stdout` just from looking at the source code?

Answer (score -1):

If you search the `termion` docs for `"cursor_pos"` you'll find the [documention for the `DetectCursorPos` trait](https://docs.rs/termion/latest/termion/cursor/trait.DetectCursorPos.html).

Rust docs for traits include an ***Implementors*** section, which shows all types that implement the trait. In this case:

> #### Implementors
>
> ```
> impl<W: Write> DetectCursorPos for W
> ```

This might be confusing at first, but it means that the trait is implemented for *any* type that also implements `Write`. You can click through the link on that type to get to the same information for `Write`, and see [all of its implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Write.html#implementors).